# How to change image path dynamically with Flask

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

Hi is there a way to dynamically load different images whenever I get into my flask app?
I've got 10 images each is named 'accueil_X' with X is 0,1,2,...

## app.py

```
@app.route('/', methods=("POST", "GET"))
def home():
    random = randrange(10)
    random_pix = 'accueil_'+str(random)+'.png'
```

## HTML

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='+{{ random_pix }}+')}}" width=100%, alt="">
```

Jinja seems to load an image named `+{{ random_pix }}+`: How can I fix this ? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want to load a random image with each refresh of the home page:

```
@app.route('/', methods=("POST", "GET"))
def home():
    random = randrange(10)
    random_pix = 'accueil_'+str(random)+'.png'

    [..]
    # i added this missing line to get code more clear
    return render_template('home.html', random_pix=random_pix)
```

> Jinja seems to load an image named **+{{ random_pix }}+**: How can I fix this ?

it's simple, just remove the `{{ }}` surrounding the variable `random_pix`

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='\'' + random_pix + '\'') }}" width=100%, alt="">
```

`jinja2` uses `{{ .. }}` to evaluate any **valid expression**

refer to this [doc](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#expressions)

Comment: @userHG if you think my answer solved your issue, please consider giving it the green tick, thx

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a [context processor](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#context-processors) which is the equivelant of Django's "template tag".

This can be used to pass a number of variables to all templates, or pass a function which can then be called in all templates.

First import the required modules, and initialise the app:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template
from random import randrange

app = Flask(__name__)
```

Then define a context processor:

```
@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def random_image():
        number = randrange(10)
        f = 'accueil_' + str(number) + '.png' 
        return url_for('static', filename=f)
    return dict(rand_im=random_image)
```

Notice you've passed the `random_image` function which can then be called in the template as `rand_im`.  Instead of putting the call to `url_for` in the template, you've done this in Python.

So you could render this with the following in any template:

```
<img src="{{ rand_im() }}" width="100%" />
```